# Code Igniter Modular Extensions Default_controller

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, modular

I am currently designing an application that needs to be modular - for this i am using the Modular Extensions - HMVC for code igniter.

I am trying to change the default_controller as defined in the application/config/config.php file to default to a module controller, for example: users/controllers/login, however no matter what i put into the default_controller setting i get 404 pages.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "index.php/modules/core/controllers/login";
 $route['default_controller'] = "/modules/core/controllers/login";
 $route['default_controller'] = "login";
 $route['default_controller'] = "./modules/core/controllers/login";
 $route['default_controller'] = APPPATH."/application/modules/core/controllers/login";
```

As you can tell my modules directory is in application/modules/ 
Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have a "core" module with a subdirectory "users": that might not work. Are you able to access the URL normally? If so, put the URI string in the route's value (everything after your base url). Remember that routes are not aware of the file system, but for replacing one response to a request with another.

Comment: going to the direct url didnt work either.. the answer below worked fine :)

Comment: No not the whole url, just the routed portion. So, if your working url is `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz`, the value of the route should be `foo/bar/baz` (although later defined routes may affect this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use module_name/controller_name

if your module is users and controller is login then default is written as

```
 $route["default_controller"] = "users/login";
```

Comment: This also works for module = users, controller = users, method = login.

Comment: thanks this worked a treat! cant believe i didnt think of this.

Comment: Boss u have to mention the function name also if it is not index. Like: $route["default_controller"] = "core/users/login"; Module = core, Controller  = Users, Method = login.